# Laravel Mysql Query Select with condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have two tables as follows:

1). urls

```
    id    domain             created_at
------------------------------------------------
    1     google.com           2016-11-30 00:00:00
    2     test.com             2016-11-29 00:00:00
    3     example.com      2016-11-26 00:00:00
```

etc..
2). links

```
     id  urls_id   end_date              created_at            status
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1     2       2016-11-30 00:00:00   2016-11-30 00:00:00     Approved
     2     2       2016-12-01 00:00:00   2016-11-30 00:00:00     Approved
     3     2       NULL                  2016-11-30 00:00:00     Approved
     4     2       2017-01-01 00:00:00   2016-12-01 00:00:00     Approved
     5     2       2016-01-01 00:00:00   2016-12-01 00:00:00     Pending
     6     3       2016-11-24 00:00:00   2016-12-01 00:00:00     Pending
     7     3       2016-01-01 00:00:00   2016-12-01 00:00:00     Approved
     8     3       NUll                  2016-12-02 00:00:00     Pending
     9     3       2016-01-08 00:00:00   2016-12-01 00:00:00     Approved
     10    3       NUll                  2016-12-02 00:00:00     Pending
```

I would like to write a MYSQL Query to return with these conditions:
**one row per domain** that follows these conditions:

```
1). end_date NOT NULL  AND
2). end_date > Carbon::now()   (I am using carbon) not expired AND
3). status is "Approved" AND
4). return latest end_date closer to present or now.
```

so for example, it will look and find all "urls_id"= 2 and select ALL status Approved and look for end_date that is NOT NULL and not expired , but since there is one Null then it wont return it, then move on to "urls_id"= 3 and we have 2 approved and both expired and there is no end_date NULL or not expired so we only will return that row of the latest end_date

here is an output

```
  id     domain          end_date_max        
  ------------------------------
  9      example.com     2016-01-08 00:00:00
```

how we can do this in one SQL query ? in Laravel or just plain Raw query

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Laravel offers a very good Active Record class so you could do this without a raw query like this :

```
$result = DB::table('urls')
            ->leftJoin('links', 'urls.id', '=', 'links.urls_id')
            ->whereNotNull('links.end_date')
            ->where('links.end_date','>', Carbon::now())
            ->where('links.status','Approved')
            ->orderBy('links.end_date','DESC')
            ->groupBy('urls.domain')
            ->get();
```

Something like this should do the trick, I did not test the code so I hope it works.

Comment: this is returning test.com , its not correct I want it to return example.com , this doesnt check ALL condition it will just get first one that meets the conditions, so its returning test.com with id =1 , basically I need to first grab ALL status="Approved" then check if at least ONE has end_date NULL or not end_date expired DONT get that whole domain , you see my point

Comment: Any other help?

Comment: You should try reversing the table in this case, but beware, if you don't have any knowledge of MySQL you should probably read a book before trying to do complex queries.
Reversing the tables example in MySQL code :
"SELECT t2.id,t2.domain,t1.end_date FROM links t1 LEFT JOIN url t2 on t2.id = t1.urls_id WHERE t1.end_date IS NOT NULL AND t1.end_date > "YOUR_CARBON_DATE_HERE" AND t1.status = 'Approved' GROUP BY  t1.end_date ORDER BY t1.end_date DESC" .

Comment: yes I never tried that reversing mysql , I knew its a complex query

Comment: Your query didnt work still its giving me the links thats Approved and >now and Not Null ?? whats the point of reversing